# Accessing currently active CLRPolicy from a loaded dll

Tags: c#, exception, c++-cli, clr, runtime-environment

I'm trying to access the application's CLR runtime host and change its policy via the poilcy manager.

The problem is that all the examples i've seen seem to create a new CLR runtime and start it the application with it.

I'm looking for a way to access the CLR runtime that's already running, and use  `SetActionOnFailure()` to change its failure policies.

So, how can i do that in C# or c++/cli ?

Examples I've found (but don't seem to work on a running CLR runtime host):

[Specifying Escalation Policy Using the CLR Hosting Interfaces](http://flylib.com/books/en/4.331.1.80/1/)

[Surviving after StackOverflowException](http://ghuron.blogspot.com/2007/08/surviving-after-stackoverflowexception.html)

Comment: You can't get an interface pointer to the runtime host without hosting the CLR yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the policy has to be set before any code is JITted, because it will be baked in during native code generation.